# Getting "Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with" error when trying to upload a file using a hidden input

Tags: java, selenium

I have a problem trying to interact with a hidden file input. I get the exception "Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with".

The code of the element I'm trying to access is the following:

```
<div style="display: block; position: absolute; overflow: hidden; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; opacity: 0; direction: ltr; z-index: 21474; left: 615px; top: 271px; width: 105px; height: 32px; visibility: hidden;">
    <input style="position: absolute; right: 0px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; font-size: 480px; font-family: sans-serif; cursor: pointer; z-index: 21480;" accept="image/*" multiple="" name="imgfile" type="file">
</div>
```

I am able to find the element using the following:

findElement(By.xpath("//*[@name='imgfile']"));
but I run the following and still does not work:

```
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
WebElement elem = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@name='imgfile']"));
String js = "arguments[0].style.visibility = 'visible';";
jse.executeScript(js, elem);
elem.sendKeys("C:\\data.txt");
```

I have tried changing many style properties like display = 'block' for instance, but it does not make a difference.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Get the div element and then change its visbility.

As per the code,you get a input element instead get the div element and then change the visibilty.

Give an **id** attribute to your div element and write a script to get element by  **document.getElementById** and give it to JavascriptExecutor for changing the visibility.

Comment: what is arguments[0]?

Comment: That way I can change the value of the property visibility to 'visible' in the web element.